# How to get the exact message from recv() in winsock programming?

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm developing a server-client application using Winsock in c++ and have a problem.

For getting the message from the client by the server I use the code below.

```
int result;
char buffer[200];

while (true)
{
    result = recv(client, buffer, 200, NULL);

    if (result > 0)
        cout << "\n\tMessage from client: \n\n\t" << message << ";";
}
```

I send the message "Hello" from the client to the server. However the buffer is actually this:

```
HelloÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you want a null terminator you have to add one yourself.

Comment: thank you. What is the null terminator exactly? and Let's say I add a null terminator or any thing like that. How may I retrieve the string from the buffer? would you please show me a sample code?

Comment: sending null-terminated strings over a network is inviting all kinds of security problems. Writing a protocol from scratch is a big task. You can save yourself a huge amount of work by using something like google protocol buffers  to encode/decode the contents of packets.

Comment: std::string str(buffer);

Comment: @RC that has exactly the same problem as the original; it requires a null terminator which clearly isn't present.

Comment: I've actually fixed the problem by adding the null terminator '\0' at the end of the message sent by the client.

Comment: True Alan, my mistake. 
memcpy(buffer+result, "\0", 1); // This should work I guess.

Answer (score 8):

Since `recv` might not receive as many bytes as you told it, you typically use a function
like this to receive specified number of bytes. Modified from [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#sendall)

```
int receiveall(int s, char *buf, int *len)
{
    int total = 0;        // how many bytes we've received
    int bytesleft = *len; // how many we have left to receive
    int n = -1;

    while(total < *len) {
        n = recv(s, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n <= 0) { break; }
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total; // return number actually received here

    return (n<=0)?-1:0; // return -1 on failure, 0 on success
}
```

It's up to you to null terminate the string if you receive string which is not null terminated.

Comment: I actually fixed the problem by adding the null terminator '\0' at the end of the message sent by the client.

Comment: @user3530012: yes but in general you should keep in mind probably that `recv` as I said might not receive all the data you tell it to (read the link I gave for more details)

Answer (score 4):

The result tells you how many bytes were received. `recv` doesn't add a terminator since, in general, network data is binary data which might not be usable as a C-style string.

You can add a terminator yourself, if you know the message won't contain the termination character:

```
buffer[result] = 0;  // make sure the buffer is large enough
```

or make a string (or vector, or whatever) from it:

```
std::string message_str(message, result);
```

Note that what you receive might not be a single "message", especially if you're uses a stream protocol like TCP. It might contain more than one message, or just the start of one.

Answer (score 1):

memset(&receive[0], 0, sizeof(receive));
To clear the buffer

Comment: Please add more description in you'r answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your buffer

```
char buffer[200] = {0};

while (true)
{
    result = recv(client, buffer, 200, NULL);

    if (result > 0)
        cout << "\n\tMessage from client: \n\n\t" << message << ";";
    memset(buffer, 0, 200);
}
```